# Serving file to angular js from web api controller

Tags: c#, .net, angularjs

So I have a pdf that I generated using PDF Sharp and saved within my App_Data folder. When the user clicks a button on my controller, I want the user be able to download that file.

I've managed to get it to work (sort of) in the sense that the user can download the file, however when they open up this pdf file the document is blank and appears to be nearly twice the size of the original file saved in my App_Data folder. I'm not sure what's going wrong, but can only guess it's something to do with how I'm reading the file and streaming that data.

Anyway this is the web api controller function:

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage DownloadPdf(int itemId)
{
    var item = _myService.GetItem(itemId);
    var result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);

    result.Content = new StreamContent(File.ReadAllBytes(HostingEnvironment.MapPath(item.ReportFilePath)));
    result.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/pdf");
    result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
    result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = Path.GetFileName(HostingEnvironment.MapPath(item.ReportFilePath));

    return result;
}
```

And this is the relevant function on my angular controller (note the businessResource call just routes the data to my web api function via an $http call):

```
$scope.downloadPdf = function() {
    businessResource.downloadPdf($scope.itemId).then(function (response) {
        var headers = response.headers;
        var filename;
        var disposition = headers('Content-Disposition');
        if (disposition && disposition.indexOf('attachment') !== -1) {
            var filenameRegex = /filename[^;=\n]*=((['"]).*?\2|[^;\n]*)/;
            var matches = filenameRegex.exec(disposition);
            if (matches != null && matches[1]) {
                filename = matches[1].replace(/['"]/g, '');
            }
        }

        // Get the blob url creator
        var urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window.mozURL || window.msURL;
                if (urlCreator) {
                    var link = document.createElement('a');

                    if ('download' in link) {

                        // Prepare a blob URL
                        var blob = new Blob([response.data], { type: headers('content-type') });
                        var url = urlCreator.createObjectURL(blob);
                        link.setAttribute('href', url);
                        link.setAttribute("download", filename);

                        // Simulate clicking the download link
                        var event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
                        event.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
                        link.dispatchEvent(event);

                    }
                }
            }, function (response) {
                notificationsService.error("Error", "Could not generate report");
            });
        }
```

So just to clarify: The call is working in the sense I'm getting a pdf file downloaded, however this file seems to contain no content when I open it in the browser/pdf reader and is nearly twice the size of the original file I'm storing in the App_Data folder.

I don't know where the data is getting corrupted.. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

The $http.get that was making the call to the web api needed to be changed from:

```
return $http.get('<end point url>);
```

to:

```
return $http.get('<end point url>', { responseType: 'arraybuffer' });
```

ie. the responseType needs to be set to 'arraybuffer'. Hope this helps someone!